# Criar tabela dinamica html definindo o class ou id para resgatar depois com jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc

Estou criando uma tabela dinamica conforme o usuário vai adicionando conteúdo.

Depois preciso pegar esses dados e criar o objeto e enviar para o controller,

para criar a tabela utilizei seguinte maneira:

```
function inserir() {

    var table = document.getElementById("tabela");

    var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
    var qtde = document.getElementById('qtde').value;
    var descricao = document.getElementById('descricao').value;
    var peso = document.getElementById('peso').value;
    var unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
    var valor = document.getElementById('valor').value;

    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
 
    cell1.innerHTML = "<td><input type='checkbox' /></td>";
    cell2.innerHTML = codigo;
    cell3.innerHTML = qtde;
    cell4.innerHTML = descricao;
    cell5.innerHTML = peso;
    cell6.innerHTML = unit;
    cell7.innerHTML = valor;
}
```

Funciona ok, consigo adicionar. Para montar o objeto estou fazendo assim:

```
    $("#btn-resgatar").click(function () {
        var todos_dados = [];

        $('.item').each(function () {

            var entidade_dados = {
                codigo: $(this).children()[0].innerText,
                qtde: $(this).children()[1].innerText,
                descricao: $(this).children()[2].innerText,
                peso: $(this).children()[3].innerText,
                unit: $(this).children()[4].innerText,
                valor: $(this).children()[5].innerText,
            };

            todos_dados.push(entidade_endereco);
        });
    });
```

mas so consigo utilizar essa funcão de pegar os dados, quando eu já deixo pré-montada a tabela.

Gostaria de definir o nome da `"class"` ou `"id"` em tempo real,
exemplo `"<tr class="item">`.

Sobre o innerHTML, vi alguns lugares que n seria a melhor forma
poderia me indicar um caminho para eu estudar?

Comment: Você tentou row.className = 'item'?

Comment: Tenho um esquema parecido com este que você precisa funcionando neste link https://github.com/cleDiego/ParetoUFPR/blob/master/js/pareto.js, repare em $("#formInsert"), $("#formUpdate") e tableUpdate(). A ideia é manter os dados em um array e sempre atualizar a tabela com estes dados. Se tiver dúvidas me avisa que posso separar melhor o que você precisa apenas.